# Why we are checking differentiability in an open interval, why not in closed interval

Tags: calculus, derivatives

When we check the differentiability of a function we will always take the domain to be an open interval.But the same definition holds for closed interval as well. Why we are considering differentiability in an open interval...Why not in a closed interval .? I was thinking the same question for a long. Please help me.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

In one dimension, it is more or less the same. In several variables, the concept of differentiability on closed subsets may be troublesome, and usually we consider only interior points of the domain.

In 1D, the derivative at the point $x=a$ of $[a,b]$ is simply the right derivative. It is easily defined, although it has a weaker meaning than the derivative at interior points.